# Xcode: momc can't compile .mom file in old project

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, build

I'm trying to build an old Xcode project from last year and I'm getting the following error from momc. I've tried reverting to Xcode 5.1.1 and then Xcode 5.0 and it's not making any difference. The project built cleanly when I last worked with it.

```
DataModelVersionCompile Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/KinsaNative.app/Kinsa.momd KinsaNative/Kinsa.xcdatamodeld
    cd /Users/mike/kinsa/KinsaNativeIOS
    setenv PATH "/Users/mike/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/mike/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Users/mike/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc -XD_MOMC_SDKROOT=/Users/mike/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphonesimulator -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphoneos /Users/mike/kinsa/KinsaNativeIOS/KinsaNative/Kinsa.xcdatamodeld /Users/mike/kinsa/KinsaNativeIOS/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/KinsaNative.app/Kinsa.momd

Assertion failed: (host_bootstrap_port != MACH_PORT_NULL), function _sim_host_bootstrap_init, file /SourceCache/Interposition_Sim/Interposition_Sim-111/libSystem/system/bootstrap.c, line 26.
2014-07-11 12:35:29.483 momc[6913:142282] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
/Users/mike/kinsa/KinsaNativeIOS/KinsaNative/Kinsa.xcdatamodeld:0: error: Compilation failed for data model at path '/Users/mike/kinsa/KinsaNativeIOS/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/KinsaNative.app/Kinsa.momd/Kinsa.mom'
```

Comment: Scrub your personal info! They'll all know you're Mike Akers now.

Comment: Huh? they just have to look at my username over here --->

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a OS X 10.10 Yosemite bug. Build works fine on a box running Mavericks.

Radar filed with apple at [rdar://17654563](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6385584100605952)

Comment: Oh I intend to... I've logged a few radars already about Xcode 5 being busted on 10.10